# Spring boot Post-construct method cached value update

Tags: spring, spring-boot

In my micro-service spring boot application I have used @PostConstruct annotation to initialize and cache some data as below,

```
  @Microservice
  @EnableRetry
  @EnableCaching
  public class OrderMicroService {
public static void main(final String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(OrderMicroService.class, args);
}

@Bean
public CacheManager cacheManager() {
    return new ConcurrentMapCacheManager("ServiceCode");
}
  }
```

My @Postconstruct method as below,

```
@Service
 public class ServiceCodeImpl implements ServiceCode {
   @PostConstruct
  public void populateMap(){
  private static HashMap<String,Orders.Service> serviceCache=new HashMap<String,Services.Service>();

// Rest call here to get some xml from other interface and caching here

  serviceCache.put(put something here);

   }
 }
```

Is their any way that i can update the cached data automatically and manually [because the .xml file getting from other interface could be modified sometime but not very often]. on any change i need to update my cache.

Comment: how about using scheduling to periodically update the cache?

Comment: @Indraneel.. Not sure. can you explain more on this please

Comment: In the populateMap method above, how are you updating the data. Are u making a rest service call or are u calling an in - application java object?  
Your statement "because the .xml file getting from other interface could be modified sometime but not very often" is not really clear.

Comment: currently i have placed the xml in classpath. it will be replaced with rest API service call to fetch from some server/system.  xml file is like master configuration file,  if any product configuration need to be changed, then it will be modified by admin team and my cache should be updated.

Comment: Okay if ur going to eventually have it replaced with a rest api call. You can use Scheduling support which comes with Spring. Check the following tutorial.  https://spring.io/guides/gs/scheduling-tasks/

Comment: You can configure a cron expression to how often the method will run. 
More information here - 
https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/scheduling/annotation/Scheduled.html

Comment: thank you,  but if i want to update the cache only if their is any change? for e.g if admin team is informed me about the change, then only i need to update, how to achieve this scenario?

Comment: If manual intervention is okay, write a rest endpoint which will call the method which will update for you.

Comment: You can call this endpoint say /refreshCache , Once it is called, you call the method with your cache updating logic.

Comment: Thank you so much. let me implement and update you